# Flutter - Connectycube call notification launch the app

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, connectycube

[image]

//Connectycube incoming call is trigered when i receive a fcm notification

i'm trying to execute a specific method from connectycube_flutter_callkit notification when i click on the accept button but it launches the app. what should i do ?

Comment: could you please explain the cases when you don't want to start the app after clicking the `Accept` button?

Comment: I just want to redirect to a jitsi call page

Comment: 'jitsi call page' isn't it part of your application?

Comment: Yeaaah actually it's not a page but a method from a plugin called jitsi_meet. Is this the issue ?? I mean should i try to build a page for jitsi call ?

Comment: but still not working